# Named entity recognition with a small data set (corpus)

Tags: continuous-deployment, named-entity-recognition, reinforcement-learning, named-entity-extraction

I want to develop a Named entity recognition system in Persian language but we have a small NER tagged corpus for training ans test. Maybe In the future we'll have a better and bigger corpus.
By the way I need a solution that get incrementally the better performance whenever the new data added without with merge the new data with old data and training from scratch.
Is there any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. With your help: it is a work in progress. It is JS and "No training ..."

Please see
https://github.com/redaktor/nlp_compromise/ !

It is a fork where I worked on NER during the last days and it will be optimized for usage with different languages !!!

It is a combination of a dictionary for words, dictionary for rules + build tool.
It would be awesome to work on persian support (I am working on german) ...
It is planned to support NER of

- 'CARDINAL' -> [ready]
- 'DATE' -> calendar based [gregorian calendar is ready]
- 'DURATION' -> see above [date ranges are ready]
- 'MEASURE' -> systems based [metric system and SI units ready, 80+ categories]
- 'MONEY' -> currencies based [ready in a few days]
- 'PERSON' -> word/rules based [english/european names are ready]
- 'ORGANIZATION'
- 'LOCATION'

I think it could be a starting point ?
I did not find the time to document the new features - feel free to open issues on github.