# New entities discovery from text

Tags: stanford-nlp, named-entity-extraction

i'm working on new entities discovery from text and was wondering if stanford nlp can be used for this purpose ?
Actually what i know is that stanford requires trained classifiers to recognize entities but if i'm not wrong it will only detect already known entities for example if your models contains "stanford is a good university" and stanford is already a know entity, if i try "fooo is a good university" it won't recognize it as a new entity

Answer (score 1):

This project should be of interest to you:

http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/patternslearning.shtml

Comment: Thank you , it 's very interesting !

Answer (score 0):

OK - if javascript is fine for you (node.js/browser) please see : http://github.com/redaktor/nlp_compromise/

This is a "No training" solution. I worked especially on NER (named entity extraction) the last days - just described it here [Named entity recognition with a small data set (corpus)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30828680/named-entity-recognition-with-a-small-data-set-corpus/31879003#31879003)

Feel free to ask me about it in the github issues because I did not document the new methods (no time and still **working on it**)

Comment: Thanks Sebastien :) i will take a look at the github and will try the js tool